# Isotope Packery Expanded State Positioning Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-isotope, packery

I'm developing a site using isotope packery with combination filters with an expanded state on click. I'm also using sort-by 'random' to sort the thumbs on page load.

The issue I'm having is that whenever I click an unfiltered thumb, the item returns to its sort-by 'name' position before expanding.

Also if I select a filter (try 'b' in the example) and then click a thumb, the item returns to its unfiltered state x and y coord before expanding/flipping.

Is there a way to disable the above so it opens at the original / filtered state x and y coord?

I'd also like the first click expanded state to return to its unexpanded state whenever I click a second thumbnail - does anyone know how to implement this too?

The example I have is here:

http://www.ilabdesign.net/test/index.html

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you want to use Packery or isotope or the packery layout with isotope?  Packery and Isotope are not designed to be used at the same time.  In addition, even though it shouldn't be used,you are not even using the actual [packery script](http://packery.metafizzy.co/packery.pkgd.min.js)  but one for Metafizzzy's packery website layout. If you meant  to use the [packery layout](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metafizzy/isotope-packery/master/packery-mode.pkgd.js) for isotope (which is what you want for use with isotope), then you need to use isotope v2, not v1.56 as you are now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help - I've now tidied things up to use the packery layout with isotope and have implemented a different click / rollover state so solved for now  :)